# GTM array returns [object Object] instead of products

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm trying to pass an array of products through to a GTM tag, when I debug I can see that the custom variable is populating correctly but when I debug the tag itself the variable just returns [object Object], [object Object] etc...

The code I'm using is below, any help/pointers appreciated!

```
function() {
var dlv = function(key){ return google_tag_manager[{{Container ID}}].dataLayer.get(key)};
var productArray = [];
    for (i=0; i < dlv("transactionProducts").length; i++) {
        var pO = {};
        pO.quantity = dlv("transactionProducts")[i].quantity;
        pO.unitPriceLessTax = dlv("transactionProducts")[i].price;
        pO.SKU = dlv("transactionProducts")[i].sku;
        pO.productName = dlv("transactionProducts")[i].name;
        productArray.push(pO);
    };
return productArray;
```

}

The variable is named {{dataLayerProductsPurchased}}

The tag script:

```
orderid : "{{dataLayerTransactionID}}",
currency: "{{dataLayerTransactionCurrency}}",
customerStatus: "",
conversionType: "{{dataLayerTransactionType}}",
customerID: "",
discountCode: "{{dataLayerPromoCode}}",
discountAmount: "0",
taxAmount: "{{dataLayerTransactionTax}}",
lineitems : "{{dataLayerProductsPurchased}}"
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are using what the function returns? The error doesn't seem to be in this part of the code.

Comment: Hey @LucaKiebel I've edited the post to show how it's being added into the tag.